# Overriding both UITabBarController & UITabBar omits UITabBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, overriding, uitabbar

in my project I had to set background image in UITabBar for that I override UITabBar with the following code:

```
@interface UITabBar (CustomImage)
@end
@implementation UITabBar (CustomImage)
  - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"tab_bg.png"];
  [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
  self.backgroundColor = [Constants getNavTintColor];
}
@end
```

It worked fine. I also needed the UITabBarController to rotate, so I used the following code:

```
@interface UITabBarController (Autorotate)
@end
@implementation UITabBarController (Autorotate)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
   UIViewController *controller = self.selectedViewController;
   if ([controller isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
       controller = [(UINavigationController *)controller visibleViewController];
   return [controller shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
}
@end
```

After adding this code rotation part is working fine but UITabBar part is not working any more. What should I do? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have to implement `-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` in UITabBarController. Just implement it in each of your view controllers, and the app should behave as you expect. (Plus, the documentation says you shouldn't have a dynamic implementation of `-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`.)

Comment: @iEamin: Really? Hm... Perhaps try creating a new project with empty view controllers that don't have any extra code, just to test it out?

Comment: Yes you are right, its work. But why isn't it working in my project. Is it because in my project each tab has navigation controller not directly view controller (navigation controller is added from IB and view controller is set as root of navigation controller)?

Comment: No, that should work too. Perhaps some of your controllers don't support autorotation, or you have changed something else...

Comment: Thanks! its working now. Sorry I missed one controller that wasn't implemented shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation to YES.